# Cannot connect to docker daemon. Is docker daemon running on host?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtual-machine

I have installed docker in Ubuntu virtualbox, but every time I start using docker(like docker ps, docker info) I get this message "Cannot connect to docker daemon. Is docker daemon running on host?". I checked the docker status and the docker service is active and running. How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is the common issue which can be resolved by _**restarting the docker**_.

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

- add your current user to docker group:

  `sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)`
- logout and login once again into the system.

---

Sometimes may help restarting of Virtual Machine.